# Cannot open catalog edit/add product after enabling developer mode

Tags: magento2, product, layout, error

I'm using magento version 2.2.5, after i enabled the developer mode, i always get an error while trying to edit one of my product or add new in back end:

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
> (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element
> 'arguments': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed
> because the content type is 'element-only'. Line: 212
>
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException):
> Element 'arguments': Character content other than whitespace is not
> allowed because the content type is 'element-only'. Line: 212
>
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException):
> Element 'arguments': Character content other than whitespace is not
> allowed because the content type is 'element-only'. Line: 212
>
> Element 'action': Character content other than whitespace is not
> allowed because the content type is 'element-only'. Line: 226

i've successfully located the cause of the problem, which is in the extension i used, but i seems cannot find the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Company_Module::js/ver2.0.x/script.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product_tabs">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab" name="credit.price.settings">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Credit Prices Settings</argument>
                    <argument name="url" xsi:type="helper" helper="Company\Module\Helper\Url::getUrl">
                        <param name="_current">0</param>
                    </argument>
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">ajax</argument>
                    <argument name="group_code" xsi:type="string">basic</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">credit-price-settings</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">credit.price.settings</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Hi are you using any third party module and which magento version you are using ?
This is not a bug, those attributes are not allowed when using referenceBlock and you should locate them in your code a remove them.

Comment: @Jack i'm using magento 2.2.5 version , how to find which file is not valid?

Comment: Is there any XML file with only `body` tag or without it or blank, I mean nothing after `body` or `page` tag ?

Comment: @kunj  i've located the source of the problem, check my updated question

Comment: I found space in this line `<argument name="url" xsi:type="helper" helper="Company\Module\Helper\Url::getUrl" >
                        <param name="_current">0</param>
                    </argument>` may be space should not there in `helper="Company\Module\Helper\Url::getUrl" >`.

Comment: @kunj still same error after i remove the space, if i comment the whole body tag the error is gone

Comment: I think issue in `action` or `argument` tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79784/discussion-between-kunj-and-tiny-dancer).

Comment: @kunj finally i got it working by beautify the whole xml code in https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer , but i still dont know what's wrong with it

Comment: Great happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Check all your layout **(.xml)** files in your custom theme and modules.

Probably You have added any unsupported character in any of the tags.

Check the `<body>` tag of the layout file. It seems there is something wrong with the body tag.

Comment: see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Just clean whitespaces.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Company_Module::js/ver2.0.x/script.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product_tabs">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab" name="credit.price.settings">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Credit Prices Settings</argument>
                    <argument name="url" xsi:type="helper" helper="Company\Module\Helper\Url::getUrl">
                        <param name="_current">0</param>
                    </argument>
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">ajax</argument>
                    <argument name="group_code" xsi:type="string">basic</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <action method="addTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">credit-price-settings</argument>
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">credit.price.settings</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```